# How to break a list of words into smaller chunks in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

My goal is to find a way in GNU Make to dynamically create rules to build sets of files in equal chunks. Let me try to explain...

Let's say I have a make variable that contains all the source files we need to build:

```
SOURCE_FILES := one.c two.c three.c four.c five.c six.c
```

Now I would like to be able to dynamically break the list of files down into N sublists and have a dynamically generated rule for each. For example, if N = 3 I would get

```
one.o two.o: one.c two.c
    @command to build just the 2 files

three.o four.o: three.o four.c
    @command to build just the 2 files

five.o six.o: five.c six.c
    @command to build just the 2 files
```

And if N = 2 I would expect to have the following rules:

```
one.o two.o three.o: one.c two.c three.c
    @command to build just the 3 files

four.o five.o six.o: four.c five.c six.c
    @command to build just the 2 files
```

I was thinking that I could possibly use `eval` to create the rule once I have the list of words broken down into sublists and I thought I could try and use `wordlist` to create the sub-lists. I can get the total number of source files with `words` but I am not sure how to do the division or iteration. I am trying to do it all in Make without using `shell` to try and keep it shell agnostic.

The whole reason for this is our proprietary compiler is expensive to call for each and every source file. But calling it once with all files as input takes way too long. So I am hoping to find a happy medium where I can create multiple rules, so I can take advantage of the `-j N` option to build in parallel.

Lastly, I plan on having a single rule which would do the linking:

```
executable.elf : one.o two.o three.o four.o five.o six.o
    @command to link the object files
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html)? I'm not *sure* they'll help, buyt they're very useful in general. You might have to use dummy `.stamp` targets though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental idea is not correct, at least not as written, before you even get to the problem of splitting files.

This rule:

```
one.o two.o: one.c two.c
        @command to build just the 2 files
```

doesn't work the way you appear to want.  An explicit rule with multiple targets doesn't mean, "run this recipe one time to create all these output files".  It is interpreted by make *exactly* as if you'd written this:

```
one.o: one.c two.c
        @command to build just the 2 files
two.o: one.c two.c
        @command to build just the 2 files
```

This means that if you enable parallel builds, make will run the recipe twice, not once.

Comment: If you are willing to require GNU make version 4.3 in your builds, that version has a new feature `&:` which are "grouped targets" that do what you want.

Comment: Hmm...that does seem incorrect. one.c -> one.o and two.c -> two.o if Make truly ends up doing two recipes and feeding both C files to each it will not work for sure. I don't think I can push the Make version to 4.3 yet, but even if I did, how would the splitting of the files work then?

Comment: You can use the `$(words ...)` function (see the GNU make manual) to split a list into smaller lists.  However because GNU make doesn't really have any functions that do math or similar, you have to choose a hardcoded size.  You can write a recursive function using `call` that will split things.  You'll have to use `eval` also to create the rules.  It will be a bit tricky but can be done.  Alternatively, you could do it all in the shell and split things in the shell and write out makefiles, that can be included.

Comment: Ok then to avoid the problem you mentioned of make doing 2 recipes anyway., how should the rules look like assuming I used `define` and `call` to do the splitting recursively based on a predefined number of files per rule?

Comment: It's very, very, very difficult to do this.  Basically you have to convert a rule that generates multiple outputs into a rule that generates a single output.  You can use a sentinel file that the rule touches, something like `.foo : one.c two.c ; @command ; touch $@`, then create another rule that has both object files depend on that one target, like this: `one.o two.o : .foo ; @:` (note this rule MUST have a recipe!!  But it can do nothing, like this example).  There are issues like if the object files are deleted but not the sentinel file it won't work, etc.

Comment: Can .foo be added to .PHONY to avoid having it be a file?

Comment: No, it can't be PHONY.  If you make it phony then everything will be rebuilt every time.  That's what .PHONY does.  It has to be a real file, with a real timestamp, so make can compare that timestamp with the timestamps of the source file to see when they're out of date.

Comment: I got it to work similarly to the way you mentioned to do it, using the two rules with the second one being empty and having an intermediary file. Any ideas on how to fix the issue you mentioned like:if the object files are deleted but not the sentinel file it won't work. Also what other issues were in your mind with the 'etc.' :)

Comment: Upgrade to GNU make 4.3 and use `&:`?

Comment: No upgrade to 4.3, instead I create the 2 rules using the sentinel file to "connect" them. If you have any thoughts on how to deal with the issue(s) you brought up, please share.

Comment: I don't.  That's why I suggested upgrading.